# Need to read the value of the selected Checkbox on Horizontal HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with the horizontal header and wanted to achieve to get the values of the selected checkbox.
Once the checkbox gets selected it should return me the values of that column for all the rows. Here is code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
function myfunc(ele) {

 var values = new Array();
       $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("tr").siblings("tr"),
              function () {
                   values.push($(this).text());
              });
    
       alert("val---" + values.join (", "));
 }
     

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.case").click(myfunc);
});
</script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Select</th>
   <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="1"/></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="2"/></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="3"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Cell phone</th>
    <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
    <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
    <td>Droid X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Rating</th>
       <td>2/5</td>
       <td>3.5/5</td>
       <td>4.5/5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <td>UK</td>
      <td>US</td>
      <td>REB</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You are going to want to get the index of the td in the tr for each checkbox.  Then you will get the text for the tds with the same index for the following trs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you include in `value="n"` where n is `1, 2, 3` in your html, we can use that information to get the correct columns based on your table.

You need to change your `click` event to the `changed` event for the checkbox. Once you have the `change` event wired, you can check if `this` (the checkbox) is `checked` with the `.checked` property. If it is, then get the `value` of that element. Then you can use jQuery to find the `tr` row for each column (1, 2 or 3) and get it's `nth` child where `n` would again be the `value` found by `this.value`. You now have the html of that child. Get it's html by `.innerHTML`. Do as you please with it.

I also added an `id` to your table to query it easier.

**EDIT:** Since you say that the data in the table is generated and your can't use `value` in your html. Then we can still do this by getting the current column by `$(this).parent().index()` and by finding the length of the children by `var childrenAmt = $('#table tr').length;` We can then loop from `1 to childrenAmt` and get the column found by `$(this).parent().index();`

You can push that data into an array and return it if you'd like.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".case").change(function(){
        if(this.checked) { // this = the current checkbox clicked
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            var childrenAmt = $('#table tr').length;
            var array = [];
            for(var i = 1; i < childrenAmt; i++) {
              var data = $('#table tr').eq(i).children()[index].innerHTML;
              array.push(data);
            }
            console.log(array);
            // return array // Do as you please with the values
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table border="1" id="table">
<tr>
  <th>Select</th>
   <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]"/></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]"/></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Cell phone</th>
    <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
    <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
    <td>Droid X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Rating</th>
       <td>2/5</td>
       <td>3.5/5</td>
       <td>4.5/5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <td>UK</td>
      <td>US</td>
      <td>REB</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Right now I am having value as static for checkbox but in real time I will not be using values as the table will be getting created on the basis of real-time data(dynamic data), in that scenario how will we track?

Comment: @SagarPahlajani How is that data created in real-time? Do you have control of it? Could you add in a `value=" + i + "` in the injected HTML? Where `i` would be a number in a loop which creates the rows for example. If you can, include how the data is created in your question.

Comment: @SagarPahlajani I've updated my answer to match your requirements of not using `value` in your html.

Comment: Thank You. Let me adopt your solution to my actual development.